# Setting a commit message / update comment when editing a page with Atlassian Confluence Python API

Tags: python, python-3.x, confluence, commit-message, atlassian-python-api

I am using the [atlassian-python-api](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/) to update a page as described in the documentation:

```
from atlassian import Confluence

conf = Confluence(url=srvr, username=usr, password=pswd)

page_id = '12345'

new_page_title = 'This is a new title'
new_page_body = '<p>This is a new body</p>'

conf.update_page(page_id, new_page_title, new_page_body)
```

This works fine. I now want to add an update comment / commit message like one can enter when editing a page manually ("*What did you change?*").

The atlassian-python-api documentation of `update_page()` has no such option. Is it possible?

I tried to change the page body to include this

```
data = {
    'id': {page_id}
    'title': new_page_title,
    'body': {
        'storage':{
            'value': new_page_body,
            'representation':'storage',
        }
    },
    'version': {
        'number': 2
    },
    'comment': 'Changed the title and the body.'
}
```

but I guess this is not how `update_page()` works, I get an

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually directly possible with `update_page()`, though you are correct, it is not documented in the [method's documentation](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html).

I found in the [source code](https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/blob/master/atlassian/confluence.py) that the method `update_page()` takes an optional argument `version_comment`. This is the comment that you want to set.

Extending your example:

```
from atlassian import Confluence

conf = Confluence(url=srvr, username=usr, password=pswd)

page_id = '12345'

new_page_title = 'This is a new title'
new_page_body = '<p>This is a new body</p>'
commit_msg = 'Changed the title and the body.'

conf.update_page(page_id, new_page_title, new_page_body, version_comment=commit_msg)
```

This should do what you want.